# Substituting INTO double quotes?

Tags: json, bash, curl, escaping

How do I substitute a thing INTO the double quotes:

```
curl -u "bk322:$passw" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{'name':"$title"}"
```

I can't make it

```
"{'name':\"$title\"}"
```

because this way JSON parser doesn't understand what I mean.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the single quotes that you need to escape?

Comment: You have to make it `"{'name':\"$title\"}"`, or `"{'name':'$title'}"`. If the JSON parser doesn't understand the result, it's because you're doing something something wrong -- something that we have no way of guessing at. (At the very least, you should post the output of `echo "{'name':\"$title\"}"`.)

Comment: And if you use single quotes on both hands: `"{'name':'$title'}"` ? What's returned message?

Comment: @KingsIndian: If you use single quotes, shell interpreter won't developp variables: you'l need to: `"{name:\"$title\"}"`.

Comment: @F.Hauri, no that's wrong. The variable will be expanded in the outer double quotes. Within double quotes, single quotes are just regular characters. This will work: `"{'name':'$title'}"`

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, but the answer I've pointed to as diseapeared.. was something like `'{name:"$title"}'`. This (I've spoken about **single** quote) won't work. But in this sample, there was no quotes around the lhs `name` *and* the rhs `$title` was double quoted.

Comment: @glennjackman: I wounder what is wrong but `"{'name':'$title'}"` doesn't work: github responds `Problems parsing JSON`.

Comment: @Adobe, does $title contain any quote characters?

Comment: @glennjackman: Nope. It's `bk_emacses`, `bk_pycalcs` -- something like that.

Comment: @Adobe, before you call curl, try `echo "{'name':'$title'}"` and see what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that it's the single-quotes that your JSON parser doesn't like.

Try:

```
curl -u "bk322:$passw" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$title\"}"
```